# Visualize the process of expand and contraction of recursion

Tags: python-3.x, sicp

I am practicing Exercise 1.17 of SICP

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
def fast_mul(a, b):
    if b == 1: return a
    else:
        if even(b): return 2 * fast_mul(a, b//2)
        if odd(b):  return a  + 2 * fast_mul(a, b//2)
def even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

def odd(n):
    return n % 2 == 1
print(fast_mul(3, 7))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 21
```

How could I see the process of expanding and contraction by adding `print` as

```
fast_mul(3,7)
3 + 2 * fast_mul(3, 3)
3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * fast_mul(3, 1))
3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * 3)
21
```

Comment: Appreciate it very much if you tried and leave an answer. @Eshonai

Comment: if you are pursuing this further, perhaps [pbd](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html) could be made to dump results like this, although I don't immediately see how to do it without dropping into the interactive debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html), although the defaults may take some hacking to return the specific details you are looking for, eg.

```
python -m trace -t fast_mul.py
```

In elisp, default tracing is closer to your desired output, eg.

```
(defun fast-mul (a b)
  (if (eq 1 b) a
    (+ (if (evenp b) 0 a) (* 2 (fast-mul a (/ b 2))))))

(trace-function 'fast-mul)
(fast-mul 3 7)

;; 1 -> (fast-mul 3 7)
;; | 2 -> (fast-mul 3 3)
;; | | 3 -> (fast-mul 3 1)
;; | | 3 <- fast-mul: 3
;; | 2 <- fast-mul: 9
;; 1 <- fast-mul: 21
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fast_mul(a, b, s, d):
    if b == 1:
        print(s,a,') '*d)
        return a
    else:
        if even(b):
            print(s+f'2 * fast_mul({a}, {b//2})',') '*d)
            return 2 * fast_mul(a, b//2, s+'2 * ( ',d+1)
        if odd(b):
            print(s+f'{a} + 2 * fast_mul({a}, {b//2})', ') '*d)
            return a  + 2 * fast_mul(a, b//2,s+f'{a} + 2 * ( ',d+1)
def even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

def odd(n):
    return n % 2 == 1
print(fast_mul(3, 7,'',0))
```

I added two more parameters in the function, s and d.

s stores the string that's carried over from the previous recursion call

d stores the depth of recursion so we can figure out how many closing brackets to add to the string.

Comment: ty, I am expecting an universal solution (some packages) to debug the recursion which independent  of specified cases.